# "favorite" column mysql

Tags: mysql, favorite

Sorry for the question, it was a bit vague, let me rephrase my question.

Tables:

- users: id, name
- activities: id, when, tagId
- tags: id, name

So the user has activities, each activity can have a tag for example "reading mail" would be a tag for an activity. So lets take an example:

- user: 1, mike
- activity: 1, today, 1
- tag: 1, reading email

And the user mike has another activity:

- activity: 2, tomorrow, 2
- tag: 1, reading email

Now you can see the user "mike" has 2 activities with "reading email", so when the user creates a lot of activities, I need to get the favorite (most used) tag.

Comment: ... what about asking a precise question ?

Comment: Give a short example of data for your tables and what you'd like the resulting query output to look like.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do... please add a few details(what is that favourite tag, and where do you get it from).

Comment: Put effort in your Q if you expect us to put it in our A's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL will return the name of the tag that is used the most
by a specific user (in this case with is 123)

if you want a listing of tags based on how often they have been used,
you can change the number in the `limit 1`.

```
select tags.name 
from tags 
left join items on tags.id=items.tagId 
where items.userId=123
group by tags.name 
order by count(items.id) 
desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and again sorry for the vague question.